# Adding path restriction for asagentsalesgroup hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have a link as below in the controller:
training/{trainingCode:.*}/book-training/{trainingSlot:.*}
Example:
/training/TRNG_DE_SPW_STAND/book-training/8797247983227 where TRNG_DE_SPW_STAND and 8797247983227 are dynamic value which I wish to restrict in ASM mode.

For that I tried adding following url patterns and it doesn't seem to work:

1. POST:/training/*/book-training/**
2. /training/*/book-training*
3. /training/{code}/book-training/**
4. /book-training/**
5. */book-training/**
6. training/{trainingCode:.*}/book-training/**

The spring file(kbecomasm-spring.xml) where I'm trying to add the pattern is following:

```
<alias name="defaultAsmSalesGroupRestrictedPathsList" alias="asmSalesGroupRestrictedPathsList" />
    <util:list id="defaultAsmSalesGroupRestrictedPathsList" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>/checkout/multi/summary/placeOrder</value>
        <value>POST:/my-account/submit-warranty</value>
        <value>POST:/my-account/my-core/core-submit</value>
        <!-- **/s/softwareRequest?softwareCode=Setup_ABS8_EOL.zip -->
        <value>POST:/s/softwareRequest</value>  
        <!-- **/training/TRNG_DE_SPW_STAND/book-training/8797247983227 -->
        <value>POST:/training/*/book-training/**</value> <!-- This doesn't work-->
    </util:list>
```

Any lead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST:/training/(.*)/book-training/**
This worked!